# Client system for media review?

Tags: admin, login, uploads, media, videos

I'm looking for a plugin, or a system, for wordpress, that would allow a client to login and see the graphic designs, video, documents, etc... that i'm currently producing for them, and allow them to leave comments.

Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named [Change Request](http://codecanyon.net/item/change-request-for-all-web-designers/236441):

> It allows your customer to easily request “changes” or “alterations” to their WordPress site. The customer requests the change by placing a sticky note ontop of the website where they would like the change to appear. Once the customer requests a change, you get sent an email and the change appears in the WordPress dashboard.

I haven’t tested it yet, but it looks promising.

For media files … just create a blog, restrict the access per [Authenticator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/authenticator/), "publish" your work there, and let the client add comments in a regular comment form.

Comment: thanks for that link. Take a look at this site: https://www.takeoffvideo.com/  I know it's a dedicated site with a specific purpose, but that's more of what i'm going for, allowing comments and details to be left about the video.